# to return a list of two values

Tags: java, list, arraylist

link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

public class Solution {

```
static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    ArrayList<Integer> aa= new ArrayList<Integer>();
   // List<Integer> bb=new ArrayList<>();
    int counta=0;
    int countb=0;
    aa.add(0);
    aa.add(1);
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if(a.get(i)>b.get(i))
        {
          counta +=1;
          aa.set(0,counta);
        //  aa.set(1,0);

        }
        if(a.get(i)<b.get(i))
        {
            countb +=1;
              aa.set(1,countb);

        }

     /*  if(a.get(i)==b.get(i))
        {
            aa.set(0,0);
            aa.set(1,0);
        } */




    }

    return aa;


}
```

Wrong Answer
Input

1 2 3
1 2 3
Expected Output

0 0

Comment: Could you please take some time and clarify your question a bit more? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`aa.add(1);` sets Bob's score to a default of 1. To fix this, replace it with `aa.add(0);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting challenge indeed, can I assume that the comparison would be for equal sized ArrayLists ?

I thought of sharing what I tried as well once I read the challenge. I assumed that we're going to check the ArrayList of equal size, so my example is mainly based on that, will have to try and find a way to check for ArrayList of multiple size and if there's not an equal number element on the other ArrayList, add to that array's score for the additional elements. If you understand what I mean, just an additional thought.

```
public List<Integer> compareValues(List<Integer>a, List<Integer>b){

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int scoreA = 0, scoreB = 0;

    int size = (a.size() < b.size())?a.size():b.size();


    for(int i =0; i < size ;i++){

        if(a.get(i)>b.get(i)){
        scoreA++;
        }

        if(a.get(i) < b.get(i)){
            scoreB++;

        }

    }

    result.add(0,scoreA);
    result.add(1,scoreB);
    return result;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

  List<Integer> ex1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
  List<Integer> ex2 = Arrays.asList(2,1,3,4);

  List<Integer>results = new ArrayList<>();

  MyClass myc = new MyClass();

  results = myc.compareValues(ex1,ex2);

  System.out.println("Score of a = " + results.get(0));
  System.out.println("Score of b = " + results.get(1));
}
```

If you noticed the ternary operator takes the smallest size, I just added that to tackle the additional thought that I had.

What do you think of my solution as well.